# How to Respond To Casual Agreement

Tags: contracts

This is part of a conversation from a help forum

Asker: Anyone got any idea how I should approach this challenge?

Responder: This is quite complex but I should be able to solve the problem. I’ll have a look in the next weeks.

Asker: That’s great! To motivate you to look into it, I would gladly offer a reward of $50 in BTC for your efforts should you find the fix for this in the next week!

Responder: You know, I’m like Linda Evangelista, I wouldn’t get out of bed for less than $10,000 a day... :smile:

Asker: But well, the way I see it :smiley: 50$ > 0$ :smiley: haha

Best way to respond?

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, would not feel this is a valid offer in **any form**. The "asker" is being light-hearted and is absolutely not serious.

If you are serious, you can test by responding with....

> I can legitimately solve this for you. My cost will be $100. Are you interested in paying for my services?

With that, things are solidified. If they respond with yes, get contact information and send a formal agreement email/letter/contract. Once they respond to the agreement, then start the work.

Chances are the asker isn't really willing to pay anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this a complex problem that you would normally charge $50 or less for?
2. Are there going to be potential gotchas half-way through?
3. Do you have a formal agreement in place?
4. How do you verify this person is who they say they are, and are willing to *actually* pay you if you solve the problem?
5. Can you solve the problem, but hold off on the solution until you *verify* the funds in your account?

This casual part sounds like either the Asker is kidding, trying to scam you, or doesn't care much about the solution.